# How to apply router-link-active to dynamic routes

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I'm trying to get [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/installation.html) (4.0.14) to apply the `router-link-active` to a dynamic route.

I currently have this router setup:

```js
// ...
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      component: HomeView,
    },
    {
      path: "/products",
      name: "products",
      component: ProductsView,
    },
    {
      path: "/products/:slug",
      component: ProductShow,
    },
  ],
});
// ...
```

My navigation is rendered as follows:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterLink } from "vue-router";

const navigation = [
  { label: "Home", href: "/" },
  { label: "Products", href: "/products" },
  { label: "About", href: "/about" },
];
</script>

<template>
  <nav>
    <ul class="flex space-x-5">
      <li v-for="link in navigation">
        <RouterLink :to="link.href" class="nav-link">
          {{ link.label }}
        </RouterLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</template>
```

Whenever I navigate to `/products` I can see the `router-link-active` & `router-link-exact-active` classes being applied. As soon as I navigate to e.g. `/products/abc`, the VUE component is displayed properly, but both classes are gone - `router-link-exact-active` understandably so, buy why is `router-link-active` not applied?

Edit: Added stackblitz demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-2xbyrc?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: Could you try to make a reproduction sample on codesandbox / codepen? The `router-link-active` should be applied indeed.

Comment: @Kapcash I added a link to demo the problem

Comment: Ok so apparently, this is a breaking-change in `vue-router`v4. See this [RFC](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0028-router-active-link.md#unrelated-but-similiar-routes) about it. Now, only parents with `children` routes will be marked as active. "Unreleated" routes (from vue-router point of vue) that have a similar path won't be marked as active anymore :(

Comment: Some news: a new feature allowing [nesting routes without components option](https://github.com/vuejs/router/issues/1174) (i.e. without having to use `<RouterView>`) will come soon, probably next version as of now. This will fix your problem :)